# How can I change Section Title Font Style in Xamarin?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this list view but i dont know how to set style for the section titles. How can it be done in Xamarin? Have not found anything for that

```
<ListView x:Name ="listView" 
            IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
            GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding sectionHeader}"
            HasUnevenRows="true">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title1}"  FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold"/>             
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title2}" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding SubTitle}" FontSize="12"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="new_feedback_0.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use a `ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate` with a `ViewCell` in the `DataTemplate`. E.g:

```
<ListView x:Name ="listView" 
      IsGroupingEnabled="true" 
      <!--GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding sectionHeader}" Not Needed anymore since you are providing your own GroupHeaderTemplate for the group header view--> 
      HasUnevenRows="true">
      <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                     <Label Text="{Binding sectionHeader}" TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Italic" />
                </ViewCell> 
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      ...
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Now you can just style the Label however you want.