# Xamarin forms: How to hide the repeated month name from the listview?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, show-hide

I have a list of events in my app(UI-1, left side screen), on there month name is repeating always.

[image]

I need to remove the repeated month name from the list and need a UI like UI-2(right side).

I am using listview for this feature and following is my code:

In my case, I need to show my list in the month order. I have added my current codes below:

**My Model Class:**

```
public class CalendarEvents
    {
        public List<EventsHB> eventsHB { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventsHB
    {
        public string month { get; set; }
        public EventTO eventTO { get; set; }
    }
    public class EventTO
    { 
        public string calendarEventId { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public long startDate { get; set; }
        public string startTime { get; set; }
    }
```

**My JSON Response:**

```
"eventsHB": [
        {
            "eventTO": {
                "calendarEventId": 136,
                "title": " school event",
                "startDate": 1561006800000,
                "startTime": "6:15 PM"
            },
            "month": "July"
        },
        {
            "eventTO": {
                "calendarEventId": 139,
                "title": "New Admission Day"
                "startDate": 1560834000000
                "startTime": "10:00 AM"
            },
            "month": "July"
        },
        {
            "eventTO": {
                "calenderId": 810354,
                "title": "event pta"
                "startDate": 1559710800000,
                "startTime": "10:00 AM"
            },
            "month": "June"
        },
       {
            "eventTO": {
                "calendarEventId": 89,
                "title": "Memorial Day Meet",
                "startDate": 1559365200000,
                "startTime": "8:00 AM"
            },
            "month": "June"
        }
    ]
```

**Xaml:**

```
 <ListView x:Name="MyEventsListview"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>

                                <StackLayout
                                    Orientation="Vertical">

                                        <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding month}"/>

                                        <StackLayout
                                Orientation="Horizontal">

                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <StackLayout
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            Orientation="Vertical">

                                                    <Label 
                                            Text="{Binding eventTO.startDate,  Converter={StaticResource dayConverter}}"/>

                                                    <Label 
                                            Text="{Binding eventTO.startDate,  Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"/>

                                                    <Label 
                                            Text="{Binding eventTO.startTime}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>

                                                <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding eventTO.title}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
              </ListView>
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var Response = await client.GetAsync("My REST Call");
                if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string response = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    myevents = new CalendarEvents();
                    if (response != "")
                    {
                        myevents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalendarEvents>(response.ToString());
                    }
                    AllItems = new ObservableCollection<EventsHB>(myevents.eventsHB);
```

I don't know what changes need to do in the model class, xaml and ViewModel for grouping the list in month view. Can anyone suggest solution hints?

Comment: as MilanG prosed in his comment you can group items - build in functionality for ListView. What I'd like to add is that I can see that you nest layouts in other layouts. Your view hierarchy looks like StackLayout->StackLayout->Grid->StackLayout. I strongly suggest you should try making it as flat as possible - it might affect performance

Comment: Check the official Group listView sample here: [customizing-list-appearance#grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a sample for you to show what model and data you should have to show a Grouped ListView in your case:

The model and data should be something like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<EventsHB> AllItems { get; set; }


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        AllItems = new ObservableCollection<EventsHB>();

        var julyGroup = new EventsHB() {month = "july"};

        julyGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "1", title = "firstTitle", startDate = "01-1-1", startTime = "01-1-1"});
        julyGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "2", title = "secondTitle", startDate = "02-1-1", startTime = "01-1-2" });
        julyGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "3", title = "thirdTitle", startDate = "02-1-1", startTime = "01-1-3" });
        julyGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "4", title = "fourthTitle", startDate = "02-1-1", startTime = "01-1-4" });

        var juneGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "june" };
        juneGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "1", title = "junefirstTitle", startDate = "01-1-1", startTime = "01-1-1" });
        juneGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "2", title = "junesecondTitle", startDate = "02-1-1", startTime = "01-1-2" });
        juneGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "3", title = "junethirdTitle", startDate = "02-1-1", startTime = "01-1-3" });
        juneGroup.Add(new EventTO() { calendarEventId = "4", title = "junefourthTitle", startDate = "02-1-1", startTime = "01-1-4" });

        AllItems.Add(julyGroup);
        AllItems.Add(juneGroup);
        //...
        //more months like April,May can be added

        BindingContext = this;
    }

}

public class EventsHB : ObservableCollection<EventTO>
{
    public string month { get; set; }
    public EventTO eventTO { get; set; }
}

public class EventTO
{
    public string calendarEventId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string startTime { get; set; }
}
```

And in your json data, the data structure seems not fit the structure I listed in my sample, so what you have to do is to convert your data to the proper structure, I write a test function and you can check if it works:

```
//A test function to convert you json array to the array we need
    void test()
    {

        EventsHB julyGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "july" }; ;
        EventsHB juneGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "june" };
        //other months group


        foreach (var item in AllItems)
        {
            EventsHB hb = item;
            if (hb.month == "july")
            {
                julyGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }
            else if (hb.month == "june")
            {
                juneGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
            }//...other months
        }

        //at last, add them to All items.
        AllItems.Add(julyGroup);
        AllItems.Add(juneGroup);
        //...add other months
    }
```

You can convert it in your own ways.

The sample is here: [grouped-listView](https://github.com/XfHua/grouped-listView)

Refer: [customizing-list-appearance#grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping)

**Update:**

Really complex to convert data structure in app side, I convert it for you and I add comments everyWhere I updated the code in the project.

The reason you get the exception was because the model `EventsHB : ObservableCollection<EventTO>`, so I create a new one here to deserialize json.

```
public class CalendarEvents
{
    //update here: here should be List<EventsHBTwo>
    public List<EventsHBTwo> eventsHB { get; set; }
}

//update use this one to shou grouped list data
public class EventsHB : ObservableCollection<EventTO>
{
    public string month { get; set; }
    public EventTO eventTO { get; set; }
}

//Update: use this one to deserialize json
public class EventsHBTwo
{
    public string month { get; set; }
    public EventTO eventTO { get; set; }
}
```

In ViewModel.cs:

```
//Update: add a new tempItem to get json data
public ObservableCollection<EventsHBTwo> tempItem
{
    get
    {
        return _tempItems;
    }
    set
    {
        _tempItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("tempItem");
    }
}
```

And then use this tempItem to get json data:

```
   tempItem = new ObservableCollection<EventsHBTwo>(myevents.eventsHB);    
   //update: converData here 
   converData(tempItem);
```

And the convert function:

```
public void converData(ObservableCollection<EventsHBTwo> allItem)
        {

            AllItems = new ObservableCollection<EventsHB>();

            EventsHB julyGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "July" };
            EventsHB juneGroup = new EventsHB() { month = "June" };

            foreach (var item in allItem)
            {
                EventsHBTwo hb = item;
                if (hb.month == "July")
                {
                    julyGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
                }
                else if (hb.month == "June")
                {
                    juneGroup.Add(hb.eventTO);
                }
            }

            //at last, add them to All items.
            AllItems.Add(julyGroup);
            AllItems.Add(juneGroup);
        }
```

Last in the xaml, add IsGroupingEnabled GroupShortNameBinding GroupDisplayBinding here:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyEventsListview"
                      RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      BackgroundColor="White"
                      IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                      GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding month}"
                      GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding month}">
```

And use startDate startTime directly instead of eventTO.startDate.

I uploaded my sample here and you can check it: [working-grouped-listView-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/working-grouped-listView-xamarin.forms)

The best way to achieve this is to ask your service side to give you json like this:

```
{"eventsHB":
    {july:[

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}
    }

    {june:[

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}

        {"eventTO":{"calendarEventId":135,}}

         ]
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution,but getting an exception. I have added my codes and exception details in the question now. The issue is something related to json deserialization, can you please help.

Comment: @SreejithSree What did you change to  json deserialization? I did not change any code of  json deserialization. Just keep it work as before.

Comment: I am using following rest api for the json data, without json deserialization how I can parse the data. http://54.208.96.132:8090/smartwcm-admin/rest/v3/calendar/list-active-events-app/applicationid/32/siteid/45/entityid/6552/entitytype/edu-school-calendar/count/20/type/all?swcmTicket=69f2ed48-6850-4e0f-a2e9-90b54c50fd28 Now I added the rest call codes into the quetsion, Please have a look.

Comment: @SreejithSree Did it work before adding my code? Or it never works?

Comment: It was working fine before adding your code, after made your changes start getting the exception.

Comment: @SreejithSree Can you try add    `ObservableCollection<EventsHB> tempItems = new ObservableCollection<EventsHB>(myevents.eventsHB);` before `foreach statement` and use `tempItems` instead of `myevents.eventsHB` in the  `foreach statement`.

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.ObjectModel.dll
Exception:>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: collection
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.CreateCopy(IEnumerable`1 collection, String paramName)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at SmartWCM.Model.MyEventsViewmodel.<MyEventsList>d__25.MoveNext()

Comment: Getting above exception when I try like your last suggestion

Comment: @SreejithSree What is the elements in tempItems? Is hb.eventTo exist? I don't have the data and can't figure out what a real problem it is. You can add a break point there to see if the type or data or other things is wrong and find out the real cause.

Comment: @SreejithSree sure, I'm looking into it and will update you later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, it is working. I already spent 2 days for this, you save me. Thanks.....

Comment: Hi Jack, Is there any way to change the textcolor and size of monthname in the list?

Comment: @SreejithSree Try the solution here:[-change-section-title-font-style-in-xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005144/how-can-i-change-section-title-font-style-in-xamarin).

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your ListView by Months. ListView provides a property named "IsGroupingEnabled" which you need to set to True.

Then you need to set GroupHeaderTemplate of the ListView as follows:

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell Height="45">
             <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
                 <Label Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="18"/>
             </Grid>
         </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Review my simple grouping [Xaml Page](https://github.com/MGohil/XFListViewSamples/blob/master/XFListViewSamples/XFListViewSamples/Views/ListViewPages/Grouping/BasicGroupingPage.xaml) and [ViewModel](https://github.com/MGohil/XFListViewSamples/blob/master/XFListViewSamples/XFListViewSamples/Views/ListViewPages/Grouping/BasicGroupingViewModel.cs)

In my sample, I have grouped by Category but in your case, you should be setting Month as your Group Key.

You can try my whole sample from [Github](https://github.com/MGohil/XFListViewSamples)

Comment: I have added all my codes into the question, can you please suggest solution hints. I already go through the links, that you are provided in the question, Still stuck on the implementation.